# heat equaiton solution on the real line uniqueness

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations

Consider a heat equation
$$u_t=u_{xx}, \quad x\in \mathbb{R},t\in(0,T]$$
and initial data $f(x)$. Then the solution to this equation exist and unique(provided $f(x)$ doesn't grow quadratic or more.) This solution can be written as
$$u(t,x)=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}G(t,y-x)f(y)dy$$
where $G(t,z)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{4\pi t}}e^{-\frac{z^2}{4t}}$ is the heat kernel. Now I can check that $u$ defined above is in fact solves the pde by differentiation.

But also, I can differentiate $G_t,G_{xx}$ and plug this into equation and notice it also satisfies it.

So, I am confused: both $u$ and $G$ solve the pde, and thus are two solutions. They look like two different functions to me. So, this is not unique then! Where is my argument wrong?

Comment: $G$ solves the PDE but not the initial condition.

Comment: @N74 and the equation for $G$ is then called Kolmogorov, while the equation for $u$ is called heat?

Comment: Sorry, never used such denominations.

Comment: @N74: applying Feynman Kac theorem once can see that $G$ is like a probability density for $X(t)$ where $dX(t)=\sqrt{2}dW(t)$, therefore when we write the equation for $G$ is should be called backward Kolmogorov, if I did not miss anything...

Comment: @Medan $G$ is the fundamental solution of the heat equation. The equation for $G$ is $G_t - G_{xx} =0$ for $t>0$ and all $x$, and $G(x,0)=\delta(x)$, where $\delta$ is the delta function centered at $x=0$. You are overcomplicating things by talking about Feynman Kac and Kolmogorov equation.

Comment: @Medan An interpretation of $G$ along the lines of what you are saying is the following: Suppose a particle starts at time $t=0$ at the origin $x=0$, and moves according to 1D Brownian motion along the $x$-axis for $t>0$. Then the probability distribution of the position of the particle is $\delta(x)$ at $t=0$, and is $G(x,t)$ at positive times $t>0$.